# Should I add column to mysql db one by one instead of in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database-schema

I am trying to add 2 new columns to two tables in mysql db

```
ALTER TABLE `exes`  ADD COLUMN `p` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT 5 AFTER `executed`, ADD COLUMN `executed_query` LONGTEXT AFTER `p`;
ALTER TABLE `exes`  ADD COLUMN `p` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT 5 AFTER `executed`, ADD COLUMN `executed_query` LONGTEXT AFTER `p`;
```

I found this schema update took very long time, several hours?

How to make it faster?

1. Should I add one new column to one new table each time?
2. Setting default value (`DEFAULT 5`) will make the schema update
   slower?

Thanks

Comment: It's slow because you're setting a new value for the column (with `DEFAULT 5`) and because (I assume) you're inserting the column _before the last column_ (with `AFTER`), so the DB engine will need to basically copy+paste the entire table on-disk. Whereas adding a new  `NULL`-able column, without a `DEFAULT` value, and at the end of the column list should be instantaneous (at least it is in other RDBMS like SQL Server)

Comment: @Dai so the problem is `DEFAULT 5` and `after executed`?

new column will be added to the last column of the table.

Comment: @Dai so the problem is `DEFAULT 5` and `after executed`?

new columns are added to the end of the column list in the schema file.

I guess it is because of default 5. but it should not take 4 hours. 

In fact, it is still running

Comment: Yes. `AFTER` makes instant algorithm unavailable, ALGORITHM=COPY which copies the whole table is used. `DEFAULT 5` causes complete table data updating - i.e. complete table's data body rewriting. But this does not cause one more rewriting, all actions are performed as one solid rewriting. Study [InnoDB and Online DDL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl.html). PS. In most cases the definite columns ordering in the table structure makes no sense.

Comment: @Akina Yes, column ordering _shouldn't_ matter, but when designing a database it's nice to have similar columns in a consistent ordering (e.g. `EntityId, Created, Modified, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy` - I wish that more tooling would show columns in a "logical" order instead of physical.

Comment: @Dai [offtop] This is a bow. If your designing tool cannot reorder the columns list output this is the tool problems. And a reason for to find another one...

Comment: @Akina So I need to remove `after executed` part? I cannot understand this..

Comment: Yes, you should remove AFTER specifications for both columns to be added, and add explicit ALGORITHM=INPLACE option. If you do not need to assign the default value `5` into newly created column for all existing rows then you should remove DEFAULT 5 option also - you may assign this value later with separate UPDATE query.

Comment: @Akina `default 5` and `after`? which one the main reason of the slowness?

Comment: *which one the main reason of the slowness?* Both. Or each. Alone DEFAULT causes in-place rewriting, alone AFTER - copying, but anycase the amount of writes is ~ the same, only the disk place to write onto differs.

Comment: @Akina thanks. so, remove `default 5` and then `UPATE` will help? why? update is not in-place writing?

Comment: UPDATE will, of course, completely rewrite table's body too... but you may (1) execute it when you have enough time for this process (2) update with small chunks (for example, 10000 rows per chunk) with some timegap between chunks which will decrease the time when the table is locked continuously and, hence, decrease the locking effect for another users.

Comment: @akina maybe I should not run four ALTER statements at one time. 

Thanks

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @RickJames mysql 5.7. 
we are considering upgrading to 8.0 now

Answer (score 0):

Since it look like it will have to copy over the table, you may as do both at once:

```
ALTER TABLE `exes`
    ADD COLUMN `p` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT 5 AFTER `executed`,
    ADD COLUMN `executed_query` LONGTEXT AFTER `p`;
```

It will essentially create a new (empty) table with all the changes, copy the data over, and rename it to move it into place.  The "copy" is the slow part.

The combining of the Alters is something you could test for yourself:

```
mysql> create table alter2(a int, b int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> alter table alter2
          add column a2 int after a,
          add column a3 int after a2;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE alter2\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: alter2
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `alter2` (
  `a` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `a2` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `a3` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `b` int DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

The `AFTER` clause forces it to rebuild the table.  In newer versions of MySQL, leaving out the `AFTER` clause lets it run much faster.  (I don't know whether two separate `ALTERs` would be required for this optimization.)